# Why int.Max+ int.Max = -2

Tags: c#, .net

```
 int a = int.MaxValue;
 int b = int.MaxValue;
 int c = a + b;
```

Why `c=-2`always? I have checked in loop also. Its seems garbage value but why `-2` only ?

Comment: Because `int.MaxValue` is the largest number an Int32 can represent, so when you try to add more to it it will wrap around.

Comment: What would you *expect* to happen? (Hint: Your code is running `unchecked`)

Comment: Because `|int.MinValue|` is actually one larger than `int.MaxValue`.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement

Comment: To hold that value, you would need to have a Long.

Comment: "Why always -2" - well, would you expect it to change randomly? That would be hard to implement and serve no purpose

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Let's play this with 4-bit integers. The max signed value is `0x7`.

```
0x7 + 0x7 = 14 = 0xE
```

`0xE` is one less than the maximum unsigned value `0xF`. The maximum unsigned value interpreted as signed is always `-1` because adding `1` to it overflows to `0` (just like `(-1) + 1 = 0`).

So you have `(-1) - 1 = -2`.

Further note that addition behaves the same way for signed and unsigned integers on a bit-level. That's why I was allowed to jump between signed and unsigned in the above statements.

---

Here's something different:

```
int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue = -2
(int.MaxValue + 1) + (int.MaxValue + 1) - 2 = -2
int.MinValue + int.MinValue - 2 = -2
0 - 2 = -2
```

So why is `int.MinValue + int.MinValue = 0`? `int.MinValue` only has the most significant bit set. Doubling `int.MinValue` therefore just shifts the MSB bit one to the left and out of the integer. The result is `0`. Like this:

```
int.MinValue + int.MinValue = 0
int.MinValue * 2 = 0
int.MinValue << 1 = 0 //int.MinValue is 0x80000000, shift out the left bit
```

You can use LINQPad to conveniently play with these expressions. You need to wrap them in `unchecked` so that the C# compiler stops warning you of all the overflows happening here.

As you can see it *is* possible to intuitively grasp [Two's Complement Arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) if you play around a little.

---

How to deal with integer overflow?

1. Either use a type that can hold the result: `(long)int.MaxValue + (long)int.MaxValue`.
2. Or, at least be notified of this probable bug: `checked(int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue)`.

Comment: +1 for explanation on how to deal with overflow, bit operations remain a mystery to a lot of people especially beginners. No matter what language some is learning a basic knowledge of how data is represented in a computer is vital

Comment: This is modular arithmetics, everything is *modulo* 4294967296. With a signed `int` we choose the "lift" from the remainder class which picks the "representative" with the least absolute value. In the ambiguous case ±2147483648, it chooses -2147483648. It is like a clock where the twelve numbers go 1,2,3,4,5,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0. The number opposite `MaxValue` is `-1`. The number opposite `MinValue` (the bottom of the clock) is `0`. When you add a number `x` to itself, you get the same as when you add the opposite number of `x` to itself. `(-1) + (-1) == -2` and `0 + 0 == 0`.

Comment: So think of `MaxValue` as the number `5` in the clock. `5+5=10≈-2`. In this clock we get the opposite number by adding ±6, which is `MinValue`. So what I call the opposite of `x` is `x+MinValue` or `x^MinValue` (flip the most significant bit (sign bit) and leave all other bits unchanged).

Answer (score 7):

Because the result of adding 2 ints with a value of `MaxValue` together and putting the result into an `int` overflows what the 32 bits in an `int` can hold.  The result is what you see:  -2 due to the resulting bit pattern and the high (sign) bit of the int now being set (called "wrap around").  It is not a random 'garbage' value, but what is to be expected.

Shown in 32 bit binary:

0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111             Notice sign bit *NOT* set  (max of signed, 32 bit int)

+

0111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111              Notice sign bit *NOT* set  (max of signed, 32 bit int)

=

1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1110               Notice sign bit *IS* set, making it a negative number

The sum is -2 in Two's complement arithmetic

More explanation here:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow

Comment: Usr's answer below is good, and correct.  But I think yours is much easier to understand for someone asking that question.

Comment: You could also note that adding 2 would carry through all those 1's, turning it into 0, thus showing that what you have there is -2